# how to show that a set is sequentially weakly closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

[In this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862610/does-weakly-sequentially-closed-imply-weakly-closed/2862636#2862636) $H$ is a infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and let $(e_n)_n$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H$, and $S = \{\sqrt{n}e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq H$.
It was said in the example that: *$S$ is weakly sequentially closed because every weakly convergent sequence in $S$ has to be bounded, so the sequence has to have at most finitely many distinct terms, and hence it stabilizes to an element of $S$.* Now this argument seems to work because it has this term $\sqrt{n}$ that cannot go to infinity (
please correct me if i got it wrong),
however if set S were defined by  $S = \{e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq H$
how could I show that he is weakly sequentially closed?
If necessary include the null vector $S \cup \{0\}$ is weakly sequentially closed?

Comment: Assume that you have a sequence $x$ of elements of $S \cup \{0\}$ that converges weakly to some $v$. If $x_n$ is infinitely often some given vector of $S$, or zero, then $v$ is said vector and we are done. Else, then for each $n$, $\langle x_p,\,e_n\rangle=0$ for large enough $p$ so that $v$ is orthogonal to $S$. Thus for each $p$, $\langle x_p,\, v\rangle=0$, so that $\|v\|^2=0$ and thus $v \in S\backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: would you also know if this is true in banach spaces in general?

Comment: What exactly is your question in the case of Banach spaces?

Comment: I saw that he argued in the end using the inner product, but if $S$ were a set in which all the elements have norm $1$ and the space was just Banach, with no inner product, I could also conclude that it is weakly sequentially closed, if so how can I argue that?

Comment: Probably not. For instance, in $\ell^1$, the sequences with norm $1$ and rational coefficients are countable and strongly dense. You’d need some sort of assumption of well-separedness of your vectors. But even then I’m not sure how to go about it.